# Is Anime recommendation allowed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

Is asking for Anime recommendation really allowed in beta? I saw some questions about this on beta but its getting down voted so I just want to make sure.

Comment: agreed, there's even a close reason for recommendation questions pointing to that meta, so there's no doubt about it. Recs are ***not*** allowed

Comment: You can ask for recommendations in our [main chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-) you know. Almost nothing is off-topic there.

Comment: @ton.yeung same goes for musics?

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ Do I need to register?

Comment: Yes, same for music